# Specified cast is not valid c#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with my system.

It says specified cast not valid.

```
foreach (var q in _list) 
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(q.BroadcastAdminID, string.Format("{0:d}", q.BrodacastDate), q.Time1 + ":00", q.BroadcastMessage, q.BroadcastMessageTagalog, q.BroadcastMessageBisaya, q.SaveCount, (bool)q.IsBroadcast);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (var q in _list)
{
    int idx = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells["BroadcastAdminID"].Value = q.BroadcastAdminID;
    dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells["BrodacastDate"].Value = string.Format("{0:d}", q.BrodacastDate);
    dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells["BroadcastMessage"].Value = q.BroadcastMessage;
    //...
    dataGridView1.Rows[idx].Cells["IsBroadcast"].Value = q.IsBroadcast;
}
```

or quite simply:

```
foreach (var q in _list)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add
    (
        new object[] 
        {
            q.BroadcastAdminID, string.Format("{0:d}", q.BrodacastDate),
            q.Time1 + ":00", q.BroadcastMessage, q.BroadcastMessageTagalog,
            q.BroadcastMessageBisaya, q.SaveCount, 
            Convert.ToBoolean(q.IsBroadcast) //<- use convert if cannot be casted
        } 
    );
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137846/discussion-on-answer-by-sadiq-specified-cast-is-not-valid-c).